# Godaddy Imagick Path configuration

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, imagick

I am using godaddy linux hosting server. Just installed fresh copy of codeigniter and navigate to my site. I see the following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning
Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Filename: Unknown
Line Number: 0
Backtrace:
```

I am trying to solve this from 2 days. In my phpinfo() i see the extension_dir is set to something like this

[image: Phpinfo()]

After that i google it and find godaddy tutorial to use Imagick Here : [Godaddy Link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/how-can-i-use-imagemagick-on-my-web-site-209)

[image]

How can i sole this problem?

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem, found a fix [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1017590/codeigniter-imagick-warning-on-godaddy-linux-hosting).

The solution is to go to your cPanel > Software > Select PHP version > Set version to 5.5.

There, imagick is checked by default but if it isn't, check it and Save.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqDdV.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Reason: 
     ImageMagick-devel-6.7.2.7-2 now supplies "libMagickWand.so.5.0.0". This can cause a PHP error.

    To check whether the Imagemagick installed or not
    i)
    WHM server:
    "WHM > Home > Software > Module Installers > PHP Pecl > Manage.

    see installed PHP Pecls (imagick 3.1.2)

    ii)
    cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini
    extension_dir  = “/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212”
    extension  = “imagick.so”

    iii)PHP info page

    iv)root # identify -version
    Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2016-06-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    Features: OpenMP

    root# which convert
    /usr/local/bin/convert

    if not showing "imagick in php info page or locate libMagickWand.so.2 not found file in server Please do below step.

    root# locate libMagickWand

    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2
    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0


    root# cp /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q 16.so.2 /usr/lib64/libMagickWand.so.2

    root# cp /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/libMagickCore-6.Q 16.so.2 /usr/lib64/libMagickCore.so.2

    root#   service httpd restart
```